# Installing rails + passenger + nginx in digitalocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, digital-ocean

When I tried to run the nginx on my droplet .. I got and error of /etc/init.d/nginx: Syntax error: newline unexpected .. I already search everything but I got no answer.

cat /etc/init.d/nginx :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white" text="black">
<center><h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have an idea with this?

Comment: `/etc/init.d/nginx` is supposed to be a script to start nginx. It is erroring because it is html. Either that or something in your question is way off (the content of the file or the file itself).

Comment: What should I do sir? do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: I'd be tempted to go back to the beginning of whatever tutorial you are following and follow the steps again very carefully. I can't even begin to predict how you've ended up with html in a script file.

Comment: As @Shadwell mentioned, something seems to have gone very wrong here! If you link to what you were following, we might have a better idea how that happened. You might want to give this tutorial a try: [How To Deploy a Rails App with Passenger and Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Thank you sir @andrewsomething .. I will just tried to re install everything and follow the link you shared.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the good comments above, I'd add that it should not be necessary to edit  /etc/init.d/nginx

Below is a default version of the script if you want to reset the file.

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          nginx
# Required-Start:    $network $remote_fs $local_fs
# Required-Stop:     $network $remote_fs $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Stop/start nginx
### END INIT INFO

# Author: Sergey Budnevitch <sb@nginx.com>

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC=nginx
NAME=nginx
CONFFILE=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/nginx
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
SLEEPSEC=1
UPGRADEWAITLOOPS=5

[ -x $DAEMON ] || exit 0

[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

DAEMON_ARGS="-c $CONFFILE $DAEMON_ARGS"

. /lib/init/vars.sh

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start()
{
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- \
        $DAEMON_ARGS
    RETVAL="$?"
    return "$RETVAL"
}

do_stop()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been stopped
    #   1 if daemon was already stopped
    #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
    #   other if a failure occurred
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
    RETVAL="$?"
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    return "$RETVAL"
}

do_reload() {
    #
```

Make sure the script is executable - chmod +x, if needed.